# Attaching files in Customer Portal

Tags: customer-portal

I am using the customer portal for clients to access some information. The clients needs to be able to upload files in customer portal.

However, with costumer portal licenses they only have access (read) to documents. Do Salesforce have some solution to attach files from customer portal?

Answer (score 5):

1. Enable `Write` access to your object, (eg Case),
2. enable the `Notes and Attachments` section on the page layout,`

Then Portal users will be able to upload files :-)

[image: Google Apps integration]